# SSL certificate for REST web services (used by Android)?

Tags: android, rest, ssl, certificate

I have a website with a number of RESTful web services that are used by an Android app. I want to let all requests go through `HTTPS`. Hence, I need an SSL certificate for my website.

**Q:** Do I need to buy an SSL certificate or can I use a self-signed certificate in this case? (I don't want to waste money on something I don't need.)

I can think of these approaches:

1. Buy an SSL certificate with Extended Validation (green address
   bar). Probably not necessary.
2. Buy an SSL certificate without Extended Validation. This should suffice, no?
3. Self-sign an SSL certificate. Not sure what this implies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your biggest concern is not spending money http://www.startssl.com/ provides free basic SSL certificates for a year so that may be worth looking into. I do not know off-hand which CAs are trusted by default in Android so it may turn out to be effectively the same as a self-signed certificate from the app's perspective.

Using a self-signed certificate would require finding a way to make sure the Android app expected that self-signed certificate and trusted not only your initial certificate but any replacement certificates in the future. I suspect this is more trouble than it is worth although I do not know much about Android development or the app in question so I may be overestimating the difficulty involved.

An EV certificate does provide a stronger guarantee to the client that the service is actually your service and owned by you but it does incur additional costs. Choosing an EV versus DV certificate becomes more of a risk/reward judgement call. Annecdotally, I typically only see EV certificates on financial sites and others where you would typically expect to find a high bar for security.

Comment: So a self-signed certificate _might_ cause troubles in the HTTPS API? I guess a DV certificate is the way to go, since I only want to avoid semi-sensitive information being sent on the net in plain text.

Comment: One more thing! What if the web hotel uses *shared hosting*? Doesn't that mean I cannot use a custom SSL certificate?

Comment: In standard SSL communications the client app will not know if it is okay to trust a self-signed certificate. You would need to provide the certificate to the client app in advance and mark it as trusted on that end. If you control the client app that might be an option however I do not know if you have enough access as an application developer to get the Android device to trust your certificate. Long-story short yes a DV certificate is probably best.

Comment: Not sure what a web hotel is exactly but you should be okay to use any standard DV or EV certificate. Sometimes special configuration is needed on the server-side if you have multiple machines hosting your site at one time or have upstream caching in place. It's usually pretty straightforward to set up with most standard web deployments however.

Comment: Re-reading your second comment I think I see what you're getting at. If you have a shared hosting provider then yes you may need to work with them to get your SSL certificate in place. Some web hosts handle SSL certificate setup differently than others and some may only support a limited number of configurations (potentially limiting your options).